# Bootstrap-datepicker error with code from their site

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I am trying to get bootstrap-datepicker to work with an app I'm building.

```
<div class="datePickerHolder">
    <div class="input-daterange input-group" id="datepicker">
        <input type="text" class="input-sm form-control" name="start" />
        <span class="input-group-addon">to</span>
        <input type="text" class="input-sm form-control" name="end" />
    </div>
</div>
```

I generated the inside of `#datePickerHolder` with [this page](http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/?markup=range&format=&weekStart=&startDate=01%2F01%2F2015&endDate=03%2F31%2F2015&startView=0&minViewMode=0&todayBtn=false&clearBtn=false&language=en&orientation=auto&multidate=&multidateSeparator=&autoclose=on&keyboardNavigation=on&forceParse=on#sandbox), and once the page is loaded I run:

```
$('.datePickerHolder .input-daterange').datepicker({
    startDate: "01/01/2015",
    endDate: "03/31/2015",
    autoclose: true
});
```

which also came from that same page.

The function runs, and the correct div is logged, but when I focus on the element, there is no calendar and this error is logged:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'left' of undefined
```

I've tried googling this, and it appears to happen primarily to people who have the input hidden. I don't have that, so I'm not sure what to do.

Any ideas would be great, and if I've forgotten to include anything please let me know.

Comment: Its pretty hard to debug errors when we can see them. Anyway you could recreate this in a Fiddle or Codepen?

Comment: Your selector for the datepicker should target the input elements. What you have targets the parent div.

Comment: Did you load jquery before the bootstrap-datepicker?

Comment: @Jasen, targeting the inputs directly also does not work, and it isn't what they do on the example site I linked to.

Comment: @Balint, yes. Otherwise I would have hit an error when running `.datepicker()` instead of when focusing on the element.

Comment: @crazymatt, I will try to get a fiddle working with this error. Not sure how to include outside libraries best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@fnsjdnfksjdb: I tried your code in plnkr and could not reproduce the issue. The code is below for your reference. 
`$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.datePickerHolder .input-daterange').datepicker({
      startDate: "01/01/2015",
      endDate: "03/31/2015",
      autoclose: true
  });
});`

http://plnkr.co/edit/SVEkzfwUnGOTeAw2TTIt?p=preview